# ordered list question

Tags: html, css, forms

```
<ol style="float:left;display:inline">
 <li style="float:left;display:inline">
   <label style="position:relative">
     <div  style="position:absolute;left:2px;background-image:someimage.png"/>
     <input type="radio"/>
           </label>
         </li>

 <li style="float:left;display:inline">
   <label style="position:relative">
     <div  style="position:absolute;left:2px;background-image:someimage.png"/>
       <input type="radio"/>
           </label>
        </li>
</ol>
```

In this code, I have tried to hide a radio button behind an image (which is specified in div tag). But this doesn't work. I don't want to specify the image directly using the img tag(which works perfectly). Any work around to achieve this?

Comment: try `style="position:absolute; left:2px; background-image: url( someimage.png );"`

Comment: DIVs are a block element, not an inline element, which means you need a closing `</div>` tag (not `<div />`).

Comment: @Steve, whether or not a closing tag is required by an HTML parser is not determined by whether an element is block- or inline-level, it's determined by HTML rules that specify certain tags as allowing (or requiring) omission of closing tags. XML (which will be used for XHTML documents served as XML) parsers allow self-closing *any* tag, and require them whenever end tags are omitted. Moreover, to an HTML parser the self-closed tag (`<tag />`) format is technically a syntax error which will be corrected to remove the slash (`<tag>`).

Comment: @eyelid - just realized that when came back the next day.  Doh!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to hide the radio button, why don't you just do something like

```
<input type="radio" class="hidden"/>

input.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the radio button outside of the parent DIV.  I think you want something like this:

```
<ol>
  <li style='position:relative'>
    <input type='radio' style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:0' />
    <div style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0;
                z-index:1;background-image:url("someimage.png")'>
      Foo          
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Other options are @AgentConundrum's `display:none` solution (which won't let you click the button, and will collapse the space) or use `visibility:hidden` (which still won't let you click the button, but will leave the empty space where the button used to be).

If you're trying to replace the appearance of the radio button, there are a lot of quick solutions to this but they use Javascript.

While I'm talking about Javascript, you can also not have a radio button and just click on your div, which can be coded to act as a radio button.

In general, it's probably not good design to hide form elements that *do* something, since you'll have to work around the interaction with them anyway every time you want to use them.  Just omit them completely and use Javascript, or evolve your design to incorporate them.

Comment: Since OP said he was trying to "hide" the radio button behind an image, I made the assumption he didn't want it clicked. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little unclear.  I think if you hid it altogether it sort of defeats the purpose. But, don't know the big picture.

Comment: The reason I'm hiding the radio button behind the img is to make the element accessible through keyboard. So visibility:hidden or display:none is not an option.

Comment: @Steve: In the code that you've suggested, where is the label tag? I need to place the label tag also. Infact moving the radio button outside of div also doesn't seem to help.

Comment: And I'm in fact using JS only to generate the above HTML that I've mentioned. All I wanted to do is associate a label tag with the input radio button and a div element. This label has to come inside the li tag

Comment: @Newbie - The `<label></label>` can be placed around the div/input combo, or inside it, wherever.  It can be styled too, to do the things that the `<li>` or `<div>` do now.  Just make sure your elements are nested properly, e.g. L-D-/D-/L not L-D-/L-/D.